# Sending user to App. If App not exist send to playstore

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, start-activity

I use this codes to send user to another applications. I wan't the user get send to playstore if the application not exist on he's phone. I was searching for examples but i didn't find anything.

```
// Launch My App one after clicking the button1
public void launchAppOne(View view) {
    Intent launchAppOne= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.android.myapp1");
    startActivity(launchAppOne);
}
// Launch My A after clicking the button2
public void launchAppTwo(View view) {
    Intent launchAppTwo = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.android.myapp2");
    startActivity(launchAppTwo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. It tries to launch the app and if it doesn't exist, the playstore page for the app is opened.

```
String packageName = "org.mozilla.firefox";
Intent intent= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if (intent != null){
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
    }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
    }
}
```